# Javascript - Input field On Change Set Cookie of Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Thanks to anyone in advance that can help me in my issue.

I'm simply trying to save the value of a form input type="text" to a cookie when the input value has changed. Think I almost had it, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have so far

-This is the javascript Set_cookie Function.

```
function Set_Cookie( name, value, expires, path, domain, secure )
{
var today = new Date();
today.setTime( today.getTime() );

if ( expires )
{
expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
}
var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );

document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) +
( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) +
( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
}
```

-This is the Function that is suppose to save the input on change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputText1').change(function () {
      Set_Cookie( 'inputText1', .val($(this)), '', '/', '', '' );
    });
});
```

-Input Field

```
input type="text" name="inputText1" id="inputText1"
```

Thanks again to anyone who can help.

Comment: If you're getting paid by the parenthesis, you should check out Lisp `:P`

Comment: I figured out the answer. Will share with all tomorrow after stackoverflow lets me lol. It blows away the competition.

Answer (score 1):

Give this project a try

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

And this tutorial will help you

http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2008/07/using-jquery-to-save-form-details/

Comment: junedkazi,  Have already spent 2 days with the jquery cookie by komodomedia.com. It works if there is one input field, But I will have several which causes that script to stop working some how. The direction I was taking might seem to solve that problem by giving each input field its own unique script.?? I'm so very lost lol.

Comment: Is ur set_cookie function being called or triggered ?

Comment: The Set_Cookie function needs to be called. I was trying to call it when the input #id value was changed...